# Question on why this list item needs float?

Tags: css, css-float

So i was looking at https://youtu.be/8gNrZ4lAnAw?t=8831 to learn how to do repsonsive sites, at step 2:27:11 he creates the navigation by

Edit:
Forgot to mention, it's mobile first, so the below css is for width > 1024, the mobile css is this:

```
nav ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 60%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: rgba(36,41,44);
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 7;
    padding-top: 3em;
}
```

1024 css

```
nav ul {
        /* NOTE position fixed to reset */
        position: inherit;
        width: auto;
        background: none;
        display: flex;
        padding-top: 0;
    }

    nav ul li {
        float: left;
    }
```

I don't understand why flex on the `ul` didn't work, that you still need to float the list item? If anyone knows what's going on that would be really helpful.

edit: html

```
<nav>
                <a href="#" class="hide-desktop">
                    <img src="images/ham.svg" alt="toggle menu" class="menu" id="menu" />
                </a>
                <ul class="show-desktop hide-mobile">
                    <li id="exitMenu" class="exit-btn hide-desktop"><img src="images/exit.svg" alt="exit menu"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: you don't need float, you can remove it

Comment: @TemaniAfif hi i just edited the question, apparently if float gets removed it doesn't work

Comment: share you html code so we can verify this

Comment: @TemaniAfif added